# react multiple images upload to firebase storage then use axios to send to backend

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm using redux-thunk, redux-firebase. I want to achieve the following tasks:

1. Upload multiple images to Firebase storage.
2. Get the URLs of uploaded images.
3. Add URLs as value to "alt" attribute into respective image tags.
4. Finally, send them (URLs) to my backend using axios.

Issue is the "result" is not waiting for URLs to come back from Firebase.
I think there is some problem with my Async/await implementation but unable to find where.

Appreciate some pointers please and thanks in advance.

```
export const postAds = (ads) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();
   
    try {
      let result = await Promise.all(
        ads.image.map((el) => {
          new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const uploadTask = firebase
              .storage()
              .ref(`images/${el.file.name}`)
              .put(el.file);
            uploadTask.on(
              "state_changed",
              (snapshot) => {
                var progress =
                  (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
              },
              //(err) => dispatch({ type: "IMAGE_UPLOAD_ERROR", err }),
              reject,
              () => {
                uploadTask.snapshot.ref
                  .getDownloadURL()
                  .then(function (downloadURL) {
                    dispatch({
                      type: "IMAGE_UPLOAD_SUCCESS",
                      payload: downloadURL,
                    });
                    let data = { ...ads, imageUrl: [] };
                    data.imageUrl.push({ downloadURL, alt: el.alt });
                    resolve(data);
                  });
              }
            );
          });
        })
      );
    
      console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the Promise inside the map callback. If there is no return value, `ads.image.map(...` will return an array containing `undefined` values. `Promise.all` expects an array of Promises.

```
export const postAds = (ads) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase }) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();
   
    try {
      let result = await Promise.all(
        ads.image.map((el) => {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const uploadTask = firebase
              .storage()
              .ref(`images/${el.file.name}`)
              .put(el.file);
            uploadTask.on(
              "state_changed",
              (snapshot) => {
                var progress =
                  (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
              },
              //(err) => dispatch({ type: "IMAGE_UPLOAD_ERROR", err }),
              reject,
              () => {
                uploadTask.snapshot.ref
                  .getDownloadURL()
                  .then(function (downloadURL) {
                    dispatch({
                      type: "IMAGE_UPLOAD_SUCCESS",
                      payload: downloadURL,
                    });
                    let data = { ...ads, imageUrl: [] };
                    data.imageUrl.push({ downloadURL, alt: el.alt });
                    resolve(data);
                  });
              }
            );
          });
        })
      );
    
      console.log(result);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
```

Check out the documentation for Array.prototype.map on mdn.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map